# Analyse MySQL data on Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

Is it possible export MySQL data to Microsoft Excell where I can analyze the data in a graphical format?

(Please tell me the procedures regarding this or guide me to any block entries or tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

You could export the data in a CSV-File and read this from excel

```
SELECT col1,col2 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: I get this error message when I use the above query: Access denied for user 'don'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: @MISS_DUKE ask your db admin go through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for example as a middleware for exporting data

Answer (score 0):

You can use "SqlYog" 

www.webyog.com

tool to import / export data to/from MySQL DB. Its a good tool for performing different operations on MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

I use Sequel Pro and the easiest way is to select all the data you want in Excel and select all in the data viewer. Then, CTRL+C/V into the Excel spreadsheet.

```
SELECT * FROM db;
```

Hope this helps.